# destroy any open menus while minimizing the main frame

Tags: cygwin, tcl, tk-toolkit

I had a problem with tcl8.5 on Cygwin
the popup menus are not destroyed and keep sticky while minimizing the main frame

Here is an example:
write the following code to the file pop_script.tcl

```
# Create a menu
set m [menu .popupMenu -takefocus 1]
$m add command -label "Example 1" -command bell
$m add command -label "Example 2" -command bell

# Create something to attach it to
pack [label .l -text "Click me!"]

# Arrange for the menu to pop up when the label is clicked
bind .l <3> {tk_popup .popupMenu %X %Y}
```

1. open Cygwin shell and Run the script using the command: wish pop_script.tcl
2. Right click the label "Click me!"
3. minimize the main frame
4. the menu keep sticky

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Notes: 
problem is not reproducible using Cygwin+tcl8.4

I use the TCL associated with the Cygwin package not the active state TCL

Comment: Also cannot reproduce with 8.6 and invoking directly the script with double click.

Comment: Thanks jerry, but I use the tcl associated with the Cygwin package and version 8.6 is not supported yet :(

Comment: What's the exact version? `info patchlevel` will report…

Comment: exact TCl version is :8.5.11